# C++ / templates / GCC 4.0 bug?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Provided the code below:

```
template<class _ResClass, class _ResLoader=DefaultLoader>
class Resource 
: public BaseResource
{
private:
    _ResClass data_;

public:
    explicit Resource(const std::string& path)
    : data_( _ResLoader::load< _ResClass >( path ))
    { };
};
```

Why would it fail but this one will work?:

```
template<class _ResClass, class _ResLoader=DefaultLoader>
class Resource 
: public BaseResource
{
private:
    _ResClass data_;

public:
    explicit Resource(const std::string& path)
    : data_( **DefaultLoader**::load< _ResClass >( path ))
    { };
};
```

Comment: Not an answer, but names like _ResLoader that begin with an underscore and an uppercase letter are reserved in C++ - you are not allowed to create such names in your own code.

Comment: And what was the error message?

Comment: What is `DefaultLoader::load`? Is it a templated member function? An internal type of `DefaultLoader`?

Comment: The error was "expected primary expression before >" which is kinda unleading...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

load is a dependant name, so

```
data_( _ResLoader::template load< _ResClass >( path ))
```

for the same reason as `typename` is needed when a dependant name is a type.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do `_ResLoader::template load< _ResClass >( path )` instead of `_ResLoader::load< _ResClass >( path )`.

When accessing a template nested withing a template parameter, you need to use the `template` keyword (same way you need to use typename keyword for types nested in template parameters).

Comment: Thanks! Your answer counts too!